# Why is `pieceOfText` undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I am creating a little guessing game involving decrypting text, but there is a variable inside my JavaScript code that is not working correctly. This variable, called `pieceOfText`, is supposed to be equal to a random piece of text generated from an array of 3 pieces of encoded text. However, when I retrieve the value of said variable, it outputs `undefined`.

Here is the code I have now:

```js
function randomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);

  return Math.floor(Math.random * (max - min + 1)) + min;
} // defines the function that gets a random number

var text = ['smell', 'cat', 'jump']; // pieces of text to decrypt
var encryptedText = []; // the decrypted pieces of text.

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  encryptedText.push(window.btoa(text[i]));
}

var pieceOfText = encryptedText[randomInt(0, 2)];
console.log(pieceOfText);
/* document.getElementById('para').innerHTML += " " + pieceOfText; */

function validateForm() {
  var form = document.forms['game']['text'];
  var input = form.value;

  if (input == "") {
    alert("Enter your answer within the input.");
    return false;
  } else if (!(/^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$/.test(input))) {
    alert("Your input contains illegal characters.");
    return false;
  } else if (input != window.atob(pieceOfText)) {
    alert("Incorrect; try again.");
    location.reload();
  } else {
    alert("Correct!");
    location.reload();
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<HEAD>
  <META CHARSET="UTF-8" />
  <TITLE>Decryption Guessing Game</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
  <p id="para">Text:</p>
  <form name="game" action="get" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    Decrypt: <input type="text" name="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Check!">
  </form>
  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">
  </SCRIPT>
</BODY>

</html>
```

The line commented out is possibly preventing my guessing game from running properly because `pieceOfText` is set to `undefined`. I was currently doing some debugging at the time when I found this out. One question I found with a similar dilemma was more oriented towards ECMAScript 6 (I'm not sure if I'm using that), and others I found weren't even related to JavaScript. So, what caused this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Well you know how `console.log` works, so did you log the value you're using to fetch the `pieceOfText` out of the Array? These are the steps you take when debugging your application.

Comment: You wrote `Math.random` instead of `Math.random()`

Comment: *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."*

Comment: I updated your demo to put the JavaScript in the proper panel. And there's no need to apologize for formatting. Just click the `Tidy` button to get it automatically formatted. You said it wasn't formatted so you could save time, but consider that others then need to spend *more* time trying to read the poorly formatted code. Please put forth the effort to post a clean question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `Math.random` instead of `Math.random()` (you forgot to actually call the function):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Decryption Guessing Game</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="para">Text:</p>
  <form name="game" action="get" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    Decrypt: <input type="text" name="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Check!">
  </form>
  <script>
    function randomInt(min, max) {
      min = Math.ceil(min);
      max = Math.floor(max);

      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    } // defines the function that gets a random number

    var text = ['smell', 'cat', 'jump']; // pieces of text to decrypt
    var encryptedText = []; // the decrypted pieces of text.

    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      encryptedText.push(window.btoa(text[i]));
    }

    var pieceOfText = encryptedText[randomInt(0, 2)];
    console.log(pieceOfText);
    /* document.getElementById('para').innerHTML += " " + pieceOfText; */

    function validateForm() {
      var form = document.forms['game']['text'];
      var input = form.value;

      if (input == "") {
        alert("Enter your answer within the input.");
        return false;
      } else if (!(/^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$/.test(input))) {
        alert("Your input contains illegal characters.");
        return false;
      } else if (input != window.atob(pieceOfText)) {
        alert("Incorrect; try again.");
        location.reload();
      } else {
        alert("Correct!");
        location.reload();
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```